# cannot add tomcat server on eclipseEE

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, tomcat

I'm trying to add a new tomcat server in eclipse. However, when I'm defining a new server, the interface seems abnormal(the icons are all red):
[image]

what's more, after I click 'Next', there is no page telling me to select Tomcat installation directory.
After I click on finish, there is a problem pop up and I cannot start the server:
[image]

Could anyone tell me what's wrong with my eclipse and what should I do? Thank you!

my environment:
eclipseEE: neon.2
os: macOS Sierra
tomcat: apache-tomcat-8.0.41

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Close Eclipse ide
2. Go to **`{workspace-directory}/.metadata/.plugins/`**
3. Delete the following folders:

   - **`org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs`**
   - **`org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs`**
   - **`org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings`**
4. Open Eclipse ide and try to configure again

*Another option is when you open Eclipse ide and choose other workspace and configure all again.*

*If the problem persist maybe your eclipse or tomcat files are corrupts, try to download and setup all again.*

Comment: Thank you for your advice! After reinstall eclipse, the problem is solved.

Comment: By the way, when I start tomcat from eclipse and go to localhost:8080, it shows HTTP status 404:The requested resource is not available. Do you know why?

Comment: It happens because eclipse uses only some files to start tomcat (basic configuration files) like for example: `catalina.policy, catalina.properties, context.xml, server.xml, tomcat-users.xml, web.xml`, so if you don't add an application then you have nothing to deploy. This is the reason for the error.